# Can't connect to Mariadb using a wordpress instance with apache2 virtualhost

Tags: php, wordpress, mariadb, apache2, virtualhost

I am just having the worst time time making this connection work. At the moment, I am able to connect to my ipv4 and see a  message that says "Error establishing database connection. I also created a test php file

Here is the setup for the test php file:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "cr-user";
$password = "password";
$db = "tr-wordpress";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

For my wp-admin:

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'tr_wordpress' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'cr_user' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
```

I get a message saying that connection failed. My database has the "cr-user" user with granted privileges to the database under localhost. The way I did it was as so:

```
CREATE USER cr_user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON tr-wordpress.* TO 'cr_user'@'localhost';    
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I then read a post about newer Mariadb versions having a bind to '127.0.0.1' line in the config file. I first tried commenting it out to see if it resolved anything. Didn't work. Then I uncommented it and set all my connections to '127.0.0.1', including test phpfile, wp-admin and mariadbuser host address.

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1' );
```

And for my Mariadb I ran this command:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Host='127.0.0.1' WHERE Host='localhost' AND User='cr_user';
UPDATE mysql.db SET Host='127.0.0.1' WHERE Host='localhost' AND User='cr_user';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It didnt work. I got the same message. Then I tried trying to connect via the ip externally by changing the previous areas from '127.0.0.1' to the ip. the change I got was that it then sais connection refused.

One thing to note is that if I run:

```
mysql -u cr_user -p'password'
```

in ubuntu's command line terminal, I can connect just fine using the username and password. It's only when going through PHP that something isn't working.

Would really appreciate some help here as I am out of ideas. Thank you!!!

Comment: "I get a message saying that connection failed." - and what is the error message that comes after "Connection failed" in your code?

Comment: Connection failed: Access denied for user 'cr-user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I fixed it. Unbelievable. All I had to do was type:  "/etc/init.d/mysql restart". It doesn't get mentioned anywhere this is necessary.

Comment: Please don't `update mysql.{any table}` either. There are plenty of user manipulation statements like `create user`  / `alter user` / `set password` that should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the port after the hostname? by ex `localhost:3306`? I mean on the mysqli_connect statement or in the variables..

That solved the issue for me.

```
$test_connect = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306".....
```